# PHP modules: how to "connect" files for AJAX requests

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, concept

Assuming I have a **file structure** like this:

```
/
index.php                   // holds db connection, login information, ...
...
/someSubSite
    content_someSite.html   // basic structure, texts, forms, ...
    styles_someSite.css     // styling of content_someSite.html
    backend_someSite.php    // should send answers of AJAX requests
    frontend_someSite.js    // sends AJAX requests
                            // (when a form is submitted)
    ...
```

The db connection in *index.php* is realized via a PDO. So, obviously, I can not directly use this db-object in *backend_someSite.php* because it is declared and initialized in *index.php* -> two different scopes, no interaction between these files.

So my question now is: What is the best way to solve this problem?

Should I just create a PDO for every php-file for every sub-site?
And share login information gathered by *index.php* via a PHP Session?

Basically the question is: What is the best way to share information or even whole PDO and other objects between *index.php* and *backend_some(sub)Site.php* when the subsites are queried via AJAX by the frontend.

Comment: PHP reads filesystem. Ajax sends to web server. You can create local_index.php in someSite directory and include index.php in the code.

Comment: Don't put your DB login information in a web accessible directory. Why wouldn't your DB connection logic just be in an include file that could be included by any subsite that needed it?

Comment: But *index.php* does a whole lot of stuff, db connection, login information and so on...wouldn't this concept result in loads of if-statements, because every sub-site has to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what else is in index.php. If it is literally just as you described, you can [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) it in `backend_someSite.php`.

If it has other things, for example anything that is output to the browser, then you should make a file that contains ONLY things like connection information (I'd suggest calling it `config.php`) and then include this file instead (both in index.php and backend_someSite.php)

Comment: Yep, index.php does a various things. So your design concept would be tiny php-scripts, for db-connection and stuff which are included in every php-file which needs a connection?! What would you do with login information when a user has logged in once? Store it in a php session?

Comment: Yes, one tiny php script that contains all information that is common to different pages. This is common practice. For login information, you would surely use a database for that. You'd only want to store the user's state in the session.

Comment: Isn't it a performance issue, when every subsite includes a file like "*dbConnection.php*"?

Comment: Absolutely not. If you were to analyse the activity of any of the popular PHP frameworks, you'd see them typically including literally hundreds of different files for every page. Reading is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try putting the code with the connection information in a separate file, calling it `connection.php`

```
<?php

try {
    $connection = new PDO('db_driver:host=myhost;dbname=db_name', 'username', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die(print ("Error!: " . $e->getMessage()));
}
?>
```

this is just an example. Then you can `include` the file in every other `.php` that needs to connect to the data base and use the `$connection` variable there.

you can do the same with session checking if you want to share session information between scripts without duplicating code.

all is up to you